Temperture Data Not showing in my weather app
I am making a weather app, using this API:
Url: "https://weatherapi-com.p.rapidapi.com/forecast.json?q=London&days=3"
Header: "X-RapidAPI-Key", "REDACTED"
Header: "X-RapidAPI-Host", "weatherapi-com.p.rapidapi.com" but my weather temperture are showing 0.0 celcius pleae resolve my issue

This is my XML code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3B87CEFA"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">



        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="26dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            app:cardElevation="14dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/card_color"
            >

            <!-- Container for LinearLayout and the nested CardView -->
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/layout_weather_data">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/location_layout"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:padding="9dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Location"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:id="@+id/location_txt"
                    android:textColor="@color/neavy"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/baseline_location_pin_24"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:id="@+id/txt_date"
                    android:text="Monday 1 January 10: 00"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:textColor="@color/light_sky" />

            </LinearLayout>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/card_weather"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
                    app:cardElevation="10dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="#659dfa"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/location_layout"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="22°"
                            android:textSize="60sp"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/osward"
                            android:textColor="@color/calcius"
                            android:id="@+id/txt_tempeture" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="100dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/sunny"
                            android:layout_gravity="start"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/txt_tempeture"
                            android:layout_marginStart="15dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/Condition_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/txt_tempeture"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:text="Mostly\nClear"
                            android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    </RelativeLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
                    app:cardElevation="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/card_weather"
                    android:layout_margin="17dp"
                    android:id="@+id/card_details_weather_card">

                    <!-- Outer LinearLayout with horizontal orientation -->
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp">

                        <!-- First inner LinearLayout for rain details -->
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="35dp"
                                android:layout_height="35dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/rain"
                                android:id="@+id/image_rain" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="30%"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:textColor="@color/neavy"
                                android:textSize="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                                android:id="@+id/txt_rain_chance" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Percipitation"
                                android:textSize="10dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/light_sky"
                                android:textStyle="italic|bold"
                                android:id="@+id/txt_perception" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <!-- Second inner LinearLayout for humidity details -->
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="35dp"
                                android:layout_height="35dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/humidity"
                                android:id="@+id/image_humidity" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="20%"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:textColor="@color/neavy"
                                android:textSize="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                                android:id="@+id/txt_humidity_chance" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Humidity"
                                android:textSize="10dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/light_sky"
                                android:textStyle="italic|bold"
                                android:id="@+id/txt_humidity" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <!-- Third inner Linear Layout for Wind Speed -->
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="35dp"
                                android:layout_height="35dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/windy"
                                android:id="@+id/image_windy" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="12Km/h"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/neavy"
                                android:textSize="10dp"
                                android:id="@+id/txt_windy_chance" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Wind Speed"
                                android:textSize="10dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/light_sky"
                                android:textStyle="italic|bold"
                                android:id="@+id/txt_windy" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/card_details_weather_card"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    android:layout_margin="14dp"
                    android:id="@+id/layout_24_hours">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Today"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/neavy"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:id="@+id/txttodayweather"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="7-Day Forecast"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
                        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/baseline_arrow_forward_ios_24"
                        android:drawablePadding="3dp"
                        android:textStyle="italic|bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/light_sky"
                        android:id="@+id/txt_text_7_day_full_weather"/>

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_hourly" />

                </RelativeLayout>



                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout_24_hours"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    android:id="@+id/other_city_layout">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Other City"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="17sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/neavy"
                        android:id="@+id/other_city_text"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/baseline_add_24"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                        android:id="@+id/add_city_icon"/>


                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_margin="15dp"
                        tools:listitem="@layout/city_design"
                        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"/>
                </RelativeLayout>





            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>




        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout> 

This is my WeatherResponse code:
package com.example.retrofitweatherapi.WeatherData;

import java.util.List;

public class WeatherResponse {

    private Location location;
    private Current current;
    private Forecast forecast;

    // Getters and Setters
    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Current getCurrent() {
        return current;
    }

    public void setCurrent(Current current) {
        this.current = current;
    }

    public Forecast getForecast() {
        return forecast;
    }

    public void setForecast(Forecast forecast) {
        this.forecast = forecast;
    }

    // Inner Classes
    public static class Location {
        private String name;
        private String localtime;
        private String region;
        private String country;

        // Getters and Setters
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getLocaltime() {
            return localtime;
        }

        public void setLocaltime(String localtime) {
            this.localtime = localtime;
        }

        public String getRegion() {
            return region;
        }

        public void setRegion(String region) {
            this.region = region;
        }

        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

        public void setCountry(String country) {
            this.country = country;
        }
    }

    public static class Current {
        private double tempC;
        private Condition condition;
        private double humidity;
        private double windKph;
        private double chancesofRain;

        // Getters and Setters
        public double getTempC() {
            return tempC;
        }

        public void setTempC(double tempC) {
            this.tempC = tempC;
        }

        public Condition getCondition() {
            return condition;
        }

        public void setCondition(Condition condition) {
            this.condition = condition;
        }

        public double getHumidity() {
            return humidity;
        }

        public void setHumidity(double humidity) {
            this.humidity = humidity;
        }

        public double getWindKph() {
            return windKph;
        }

        public void setWindKph(double windKph) {
            this.windKph = windKph;
        }

        public double getChancesofRain() {
            return chancesofRain;
        }

        public void setChancesofRain(double chancesofRain) {
            this.chancesofRain = chancesofRain;
        }
    }

    public static class Condition {
        private String text;
        private String icon;

        // Getters and Setters
        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public String getIcon() {
            return icon;
        }

        public void setIcon(String icon) {
            this.icon = icon;
        }
    }

    public static class Forecast {
        private List<ForecastDay> forecastday;

        // Getters and Setters
        public List<ForecastDay> getForecastday() {
            return forecastday;
        }

        public void setForecastday(List<ForecastDay> forecastday) {
            this.forecastday = forecastday;
        }
    }

    public static class ForecastDay {
        private String date;
        private List<Hour> hour;
        private String forecastDay;

        // Getters and Setters
        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public void setDate(String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }

        public List<Hour> getHour() {
            return hour;
        }

        public void setHour(List<Hour> hour) {
            this.hour = hour;
        }

        public String getForecastDay() {
            return forecastDay;
        }

        public void setForecastDay(String forecastDay) {
            this.forecastDay = forecastDay;
        }
    }


    public static class Hour {
        private String time;
        private double tempC;
        private Condition condition;

        // Getters and Setters
        public String getTime() {
            return time;
        }

        public void setTime(String time) {
            this.time = time;
        }

        public double getTempC() {
            return tempC;
        }

        public void setTempC(double tempC) {
            this.tempC = tempC;
        }

        public Condition getCondition() {
            return condition;
        }

        public void setCondition(Condition condition) {
            this.condition = condition;
        }
    }
}

This is my WeatherInterface class:
package com.example.retrofitweatherapi.WeatherData;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Header;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface Weatherinterface
{
    @GET("forecast.json")
    Call<WeatherResponse>getWeatherData(
            @Header("X-RapidAPI-Key") String api_key,
            @Header("X-RapidAPI-Host") String apiHost,
            @Query("q") String location,
            @Query("days") int days
    );
}

This is my ApiClient:
package com.example.retrofitweatherapi.WeatherData;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class ApiClient
{
    private static final String BASE_URL="https://weatherapi-com.p.rapidapi.com/";

    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance(){
        if (retrofit==null){
            retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}

This is my MainActivity.java code:
package com.example.retrofitweatherapi;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;

import com.example.retrofitweatherapi.WeatherData.ApiClient;
import com.example.retrofitweatherapi.WeatherData.HourModel;
import com.example.retrofitweatherapi.WeatherData.HourlyWeatherAdapter;
import com.example.retrofitweatherapi.WeatherData.WeatherResponse;
import com.example.retrofitweatherapi.WeatherData.Weatherinterface;
import com.example.retrofitweatherapi.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityMainBinding binding;
    //1caea1f23fmsh7b6dcc08a73f460p1be99bjsnbe0dc6d81ffa
    Weatherinterface weatherinterface;
    private static final String API_KEY = "1caea1f23fmsh7b6dcc08a73f460p1be99bjsnbe0dc6d81ffa";
    private static final String API_HOST = "weatherapi-com.p.rapidapi.com";
    private HourlyWeatherAdapter adapter;
    private List<HourModel>hourlist;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding=ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view=binding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view);

        weatherinterface= ApiClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(Weatherinterface.class);


        hourlist=new ArrayList<>();

        adapter=new HourlyWeatherAdapter(getApplicationContext(),hourlist);
        binding.recyclerviewHourly.setAdapter(adapter);
        binding.recyclerviewHourly.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));


        fetchWeatherData("London",3);


    }

    private void fetchWeatherData(String location,int days)
    {
        Call<WeatherResponse>call=weatherinterface.getWeatherData(API_KEY,API_HOST,location,days);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<WeatherResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<WeatherResponse> call, Response<WeatherResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()&&response.body()!=null){
                    WeatherResponse weatherResponse=response.body();
                   UpdateUI(weatherResponse);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to fetch weather data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<WeatherResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
    private void UpdateUI(WeatherResponse weatherResponse){
        WeatherResponse.Current current=weatherResponse.getCurrent();
        WeatherResponse.Condition condition=current.getCondition();

        binding.locationTxt.setText(weatherResponse.getLocation().getName());
        binding.txtDate.setText(weatherResponse.getLocation().getLocaltime());
        binding.txtTempeture.setText(String.format("%.1f°C",weatherResponse.getCurrent().getTempC()));
        binding.ConditionText.setText(condition.getText());
        Picasso.get().load("https:" + condition.getIcon());

        binding.txtRainChance.setText(String.format("%.0f%%",current.getChancesofRain()));
        binding.txtHumidityChance.setText(String.format("%.0f%%",current.getHumidity()));
        binding.txtWindyChance.setText(String.format("%.0f km/h",current.getWindKph()));


        // Clear and update the hourly weather data
        hourlist.clear();

        for (WeatherResponse.Hour hour:weatherResponse.getForecast().getForecastday().get(0).getHour()){
            String time=hour.getTime().split(" ")[1];
            String temp=String.format("%.1f°C",hour.getTempC());
            String imageurl= "https:"+hour.getCondition().getIcon();
            hourlist.add(new HourModel(time,temp,imageurl));
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

With all this, the temperature data is still not showing. What can I do to fix it?

You aren't using the correct variables in your WeatherResponse Class.
For Example:
In your code, your used the variable: (private double tempC;)
What it actually should be, is: (public double temp_c;)
Here temp_c is the object in the Json Response.
